# H3 float issue in google chrome

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML/CSS code which was working properly in all the browsers but it is suddenly not working properly in chrome.

Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/zg6y24ju/

```
<div class='container'>
<h3 style='float:left;'>
LEFT OPTIONS
</h3>

 <h3 style='float:right;'>
RIGHT OPTIONS
</h3>
</div>
```

I have a div container which contains two h3 tags one floating to left and one to right.
In all browsers except Chrome, the text in h3 appears correctly without any wrapping.
However in Chrome, the text after blank space goes to the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That *is* odd, and it seems to be caused by this style:

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```

You can prevent it by adding this style to `h3`:

```
h3 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like it is text-rendering property which is causing the issue. It was causing issues everywhere else.